# Convert Selenium WindowHandle to WinAPI hWnd

Tags: selenium, winapi, selenium-webdriver, hwnd

Is there any way I can convert the Window handle in Selenium into a *real* window handle to use in WinAPI calls?

```
Driver.CurrentWindow is returning "2dbb281a-e0aa-454c-8e40-2cdb7de7f238"
```

I want to get a handle I can use with the `GetWindowThreadProcessId` method in `user32.dll`.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowThreadProcessId.html

> Specifically, I'm needing to do it for IE.  I can see there is a dirty (a.k.a rather cool) hack for FireFox as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11667090/442351).